# Norm of an linear operator $T:C(X, \mathbb{R} )\rightarrow C(X, \mathbb{R} )$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the next linear operator  $T:C(X, \mathbb{R} )\rightarrow  C(Y, \mathbb{R} )$, where $T$ is positive and continuous.
Prove that $||T||=||T(1)||_{\infty}$, $1\in C(X, \mathbb{R}) $ is the constant application equal to 1 and $||T(f) |||_{\infty}= sup_{x\in X} |T(f) (x) |$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** We will have $-T(1)(x)\le T(f)(x)\le T(1)(x)$ for all $x\in X$, whenever $\|f\|_\infty\le 1$, by positivity of $T$.

> **Hidden hint:** Both functions $1-f$ and $f-(-1)$ are $\ge 0$, so $T(1-f)$ and $T(f+1)$ are $\ge 0$, too.